# Listing the options of a Select gives different results in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, select

In my JavaScript code I'm trying to list the options (and their values) of a Select.  Here's a snippet of code (I'm using the YUI2 library...the log statement just puts text in a logger):

```
for (var opt in mySelect.options)
{
  YAHOO.log('my opt, val: ' + opt + ', ' + mySelect.options[opt].value);
}
```

In Firefox I get the following (correct) output:

```
my opt, val: 0, 2
my opt, val: 1, 1
my opt, val: 2, 3
my opt, val: 3, 4
my opt, val: 4, 0
```

but in Internet Explorer 7 I get:

```
my opt, val: language, undefined
my opt, val: scrollHeight, undefined
my opt, val: isTextEdit, undefined
my opt, val: currentStyle, undefined
my opt, val: document, undefined
```

I'm a bit surprised to say the least.  I even tried for (var opt in (mySelect.options)) and I changed the name of the variable opt just in case.  Nothing made a difference.

If I code the loop like this:

```
for (var idx=0; idx< mySelect.options.length; idx++)
{
  YAHOO.log('my idx, val: ' + idx + ', ' + mySelect.options[idx].value);
}
```

then IE works fine as well.

Why did the first way not work?  I thought the for/in loop worked the same way as a for loop.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` / `in` loops loop over every property in an object.
You aren't seeing these properties in Firefox because they're marked as `[DontEnum]`.

You should use ordinary `for` loops to loop over arrays.
For ordinary arrays, you can get away with a `for` / `in` loop by skipping keys if `!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`, but I'm not sure whether that will work for DOM objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I definitely misunderstood how for/in works and the pitfalls with arrays.  I did more research and found my question had already been answered here - I just didn't know the right way to search for it!  Here's that answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays

Thank you again for your help...going to change my code now!